# svg -> img conversion not preserving linked font

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to convert svgs to png's in javascript by way of canvas elements (inspired by "https://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844"), but I'm having issues rendering fonts which I'm linking to.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2chtz7rx/1/

Html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Creepster:400,400" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<svg id="svg">
  <text style="min-height: 43px; margin: 20px; font-size: 200%; font-family: Creepster; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal" x="50%" y="35" text-anchor="middle">FONT</text>
</svg>
<button id="button">render canvas</button>
<img id="img">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg'))
  var svg = new Blob([str], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
  var url = self.URL.createObjectURL(svg);
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    self.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

Notice how the svg renders fine, but when creating the img using the svg's url it fails to render the font correctly, and reverts to Times new Roman.

Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: You know that you could load the svg using `new Image` and then draw that image into your canvas? That should preserve any fonts and rendering of the SVG while treating it like a regular image.

Comment: I had actually tried that earlier.  but switching out "var img = document.getElementById('img')" with "var img = new Image()" has the exact same result.

Comment: No, thats not what I meant. Basically, try `var i = new Image; i.src = 'path/to/SVG.svg'; canvasContext.drawImage(i, 0, 0)`. Since you can use an `svg` as a source for an `<img>` element and you can use an `<img>` element as a source for `drawImage`, it should fix your problem. (Although, since the font is not included in an external SVG this might not actually work... in this case - maybe if you convert it to a data uri first, ...)

Comment: I dont think that will work unless the font is embedded in the svg.

Comment: DId you ever come up with a solution?
Having the same Problem. Loading the SVG with new Image(), but the font, even though it exists in my VueProject, is not applied to the SVG